# Is it possible to manipulate the filecache size of a Node in nextcloud?

Tags: php, nextcloud

I am developing a Nextcloud app.

I have a directory that's linked to another and so Nextcloud thinks I am using the double amount of space but in reality that's not the case so I would like to manipulate the size of the filecache entry.

I've already searched for a bit but only found some deprecated stuff, which used Hooks, since it's deprecated I would like to use another technique. Currently I am trying to update the Entry after the "NodeAddedToCache" or "FolderScannedEvent" using an Eventlistener class. But it doesn't seem to be executed and I don't really know how I should test/debug that since I can't find a good documentation about which Events will be fired at what situations or where I could find the Logs for this stuff.

My Current code looks like this:

lib/AppInfo/Application.php

```php
namespace OCA\Application\AppInfo;

use OCA\Application\Event\RegistrationEventListener;
use OCP\AppFramework\App;
use OCP\EventDispatcher\IEventDispatcher;
use OCP\Files\Events\FolderScannedEvent;

class Application extends App {
    public const APP_ID = 'application';

    public function __construct(IEventDispatcher $dispatcher) {
        parent::__construct(self::APP_ID);
        $dispatcher->addServiceListener(FolderScannedEvent::class, RegistrationEventListener::class, 1);
    }
}
```

RegistrationEventListener.php

```php
<?php
namespace OCA\Application\Event;

use OC\Files\Storage\Storage;
use OCA\AdminAudit\AuditLogger;
use OCP\EventDispatcher\Event;
use OCP\EventDispatcher\IEventListener;
use OCP\Files\Events\FolderScannedEvent;

class RegistrationEventListener implements IEventListener {
    private $logger;
    private $storage;

    public function __construct(AuditLogger $logger, Storage $storage)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->storage = $storage;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function handle(FolderScannedEvent|Event $event): void
    {
        if(is_link($event->getAbsolutePath())) {
            $fileId = $this->storage->getCache()->getId($event->getAbsolutePath());
            $this->storage->getCache()->update($fileId, [
                'size'  => 0
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about symbolic links? Have you tried reporting the issue to the software vendor? Just asking, because last time I looked Nextcloud was still Free Software and wouldn't it be better that the quota component supports symbolic linking? This normally works with contributing upstream.

Comment: Well yes but i saw another thread that proposed to add symlink support, but nextcloud verified, that there are no plans of supporting this edge case and mounts are not what i need, since i want to be able to link single files and not only directories.

Comment: @hakre The issue with symbolic links, as great as they are is: they are not supported under MS Windows due to the very limited set of file systems supported there. That makes it an issue for projects like nextcloud, trying to stay os neutral.

Comment: @arkascha: Which they do through containerization and even older forms of configuration, e.g. via files containing settings.

Comment: @hakre I fail to see what one has to do with the other. But what do I know ...

Comment: Well, let's say the filesystem in use does not support symlinks. Fine for Next Cloud. On a different system it might support symbolic links. Fine for Next Cloud, enable the setting to support symbolic links for quota. You either contain the file-system (in the container) or the setting for the feature the file-system may support. So either the application has support for it or not, and if it has, there might be a flag for it. /E: for this comment example, there is a flag, but IIRC it is not exactly that what OP is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to consume the Nextcloud Filescanner events, you should use the `IBootstrap->register()` method of your `Application` class like this:

`AppInfo/Application.php`

```php
<?php

namespace OCA\Application\AppInfo;

use OCA\Application\Listener\FileCacheListener;
use OCP\AppFramework\App;
use OCP\AppFramework\Bootstrap\IBootContext;
use OCP\AppFramework\Bootstrap\IBootstrap;
use OCP\AppFramework\Bootstrap\IRegistrationContext;
use OCP\Files\Events\FileCacheUpdated;
use OCP\Files\Events\NodeAddedToCache;
use OCP\Files\Events\NodeRemovedFromCache;

class Application extends App implements IBootstrap {
    public const APP_NAME = 'application';

    public function __construct(array $urlParams = []) {
        parent::__construct(self::APP_NAME, $urlParams);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function register(IRegistrationContext $context): void {
        $context->registerEventListener(NodeAddedToCache::class, FileCacheListener::class);
        $context->registerEventListener(FileCacheUpdated::class, FileCacheListener::class);
        $context->registerEventListener(NodeRemovedFromCache::class, FileCacheListener::class);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function boot(IBootContext $context): void {
    }
}
```

Your listener could look like this (`Listener/FileCacheListener.php`):

```php
<?php

namespace OCA\Application\Listener;

use OCP\EventDispatcher\Event;
use OCP\EventDispatcher\IEventListener;
use OCP\Files\Events\FileCacheUpdated;
use OCP\Files\Events\NodeAddedToCache;
use OCP\Files\Events\NodeRemovedFromCache;

class FileCacheListener implements IEventListener {
    public function handle(Event $event) : void {
        if (!($event instanceof NodeAddedToCache) 
            && !($event instanceof FileCacheUpdated)
            && !($event instanceof NodeRemovedFromCache)
        ) {
            return;
        }

        // Do something here ...
        
    }
}
```

You can check if the listener is called by adding/updating/removing a file on the filesystem directly and then call `php occ files:scan --all`.

Note that the events above will only be fired when a file gets scanned and it has changed. If you would like to capture individual events (like file uploads etc.), you can find a working example [here](https://github.com/nextcloud/files_fulltextsearch/blob/2321c53413b6d56707783a3ffad6bd6c49f62951/lib/AppInfo/Application.php#L78). Good luck :-)